# Why am getting EOL error while loading data in Weka?

Tags: weka, eol

Following is the code in my arff file:

```
@relation superstore

@attribute t1 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t2 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t3 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t4 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t5 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t6 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t7 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t8 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t9 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t10 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}

@data
milk,egg,bread,?,?,chip,?
?,egg,?,?,popcorn,chip,beer
?,egg,bread,?,?,chip,?
milk,egg,bread,?,popcorn,chip,beer
milk,?,bread,?,?,?,beer
?,egg,bread,?,?,?,beer
milk,?,bread,?,?,chip,?
milk,egg,bread,butter,?,chip,?
milk,egg,?,butter,?,chip,?
```

While loading this data in Weka, it indicates EOL error on line 16 but i have checked multiple time and I have not found any abnormality here. Kindly help me out here..

Answer (score 0):

You have defined 10 columns, but using only 6 for data.

Your file should look like this:

```
@relation superstore

@attribute t1 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t2 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t3 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t4 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t5 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}
@attribute t6 {milk,egg,bread,butter,popcorn,chip,beer}

@data
milk,egg,bread,?,?,chip,?
?,egg,?,?,popcorn,chip,beer
?,egg,bread,?,?,chip,?
milk,egg,bread,?,popcorn,chip,beer
milk,?,bread,?,?,?,beer
?,egg,bread,?,?,?,beer
milk,?,bread,?,?,chip,?
milk,egg,bread,butter,?,chip,?
milk,egg,?,butter,?,chip,?
```

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark my answer as accepted - click on the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in